# Wrapping child classes of templated base class in Cython

Tags: c++, templates, cython, template-specialization, base-class

So I am writing a Python API for a C++ library using Cython. I have three classes with almost identical functionality: `A`, `B`, and `C`. This difference is only how one of their objects is built on initialization and some constants.

Originally, I have wrote them all out as separate classes and then could define them via extern in my cython code. This compiles and works well but there is a lot of repeated code and I would really like this project to be more DRY.

So I decided to write a base class for `A`, `B`, and `C` that implemented most of the functionality once. However, I needed to template that base class and this is causing me a nightmare when I try to define everything in Cython. Here is a toy example of what I'm talking about (ignore missed semi-colons etc, if you find them). This is my "classes.h" file

```
int library_method_load(std::string file_name){
    return std::string.length();
}

template <class T>
class BaseClass{
public:
    T important_obj;
    BaseClass(std::string file_name){ important_obj = library_method(file_name);};
    virtual T library_method(std::string file_name) = 0;
    // Important logicks...
    ~BaseClass(){};
}



class A : public BaseClass<int> {
    A(std::string file_name): BaseClass<int>(file_name){};
    int library_method(std::string file_name){ return library_method_load(file_name);};
    ~A(){};
}
```

When I try to wrap this, if I don't tell cython about the base class, I get undefined symbols. If I try to define the base class, the templating causes problems. The latter could be due to the fact that I don't know the syntax properly for inheriting templated base classes.

Here is my current attempt

```
#distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef extern from "classes.h":
    cppclass BaseClass[T]:
        BaseClass(string file_name)

cdef extern from "classes.h":
    cppclass A(BaseClass[int]):
        A(string file_name)

cdef class PyBase:
    cdef BaseClass* wrapped

cdef class PyA(PyBase):
    def __cinit__(self, string file_name):
        self.wrapped = <BaseClass[int]*> new A(file_name)
```

Doing this gives me the following compiler error:

> Error compiling Cython file:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------ ...
>
> cdef class PyA(PyBase):
>
> ```
> def __cinit__(self, string file_name):
>     self.wrapped = <BaseClass[int]*> new A(file_name)
> ```
>
> ### ^
>
> wrapper.pyx:23:23: Cannot assign type 'BaseClass[int] *' to
>   'BaseClass[T] *' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       setup(name="test", version="1.0.0", ext_modules=cythonize([rk]))   File
>   "/home/jacob/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py",
>   line 1027, in cythonize
>       cythonize_one(*args)   File "/home/jacob/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py",
>   line 1149, in cythonize_one
>       raise CompileError(None, pyx_file) Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: wrapper.pyx

Does anyone know how to do this? Clearly my template substituion is off. Should I stick with the repetitive code instead? Are there other clever solutions?

Comment: Not sure to understand what do you want; are you sure you're not looking for CRPT ([Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern))?

Comment: You need to show your cython wrapper, otherwise nobody can tell what is your problem, see [mcve]. Please make sure, that your example is minimal - probably only one subclass (and  not 3) is sufficient to show the problem.

Comment: I think the issue is that you don't actually have a common base class - they all have slightly different base classes generated by the template, and it's actually pretty hard to create good Cython wrappers for template classes without duplication. One solution is to [generate the repetitive code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436593/cython-templates-in-python-class-wrappers/31457216#31457216).

Comment: This approach will not work. In C++, calling a virtual method from a base class constructor will _not_ invoke an override in some derived class: it will invoke the base class implementation of the virtual method (if it exists).

Comment: In fact, relying on a virtual method is complicating a simple requirement. Define the BaseClass constructor with a T parameter, and provide this argument from the derived class (as the result of invoking its custom loader method).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to drop `PyBase` because in `cdef BaseClass* wrapped` the template argument for `BaseClass` is missing, which makes the line meaningless.

E.g.:

```
cdef class PyA(PyBase):
    cdef A* wrapped
    def __cinit__(self, string file_name):
        self.wrapped = new A(file_name)
```

(I am not sure though if you can pass a C++ object into `__init__` and `__cinit__`)

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It compiles but complains about an undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct.

Comment: @batconjurer You need to link Python library. `-lpython`.

Comment: I tried this, but now it complains that the there is an undefined symbol for the BaseClass library method. Including it in the extern defs doesn't seem to help.