# Cython same classes with different types

Tags: python, cython, gmpy

I have two cdef classes `B` and `C` whose methods are **exactly** the same. The only difference between them is the type of their attributes: one has `mpz` attributes, the other one `int` attributes.

My first guess was to use an abstract class `A` which would be overriden by `B` and `C`. The problem is that Cython apparently doesn't want me to override attributes (plus, which type should I give to the attribute of the abstract class?). The error I got by doing this was:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef class TestModularNumber:
    cdef readonly mpz value, modulo

cdef class TestInheritance(TestModularNumber):
    cdef readonly int value, modulo                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

finite_field/testmodular.pxd:10:22: 'value' redeclared
```

My second guess was to use a single class with fused type like this:

```
ctypedef fused mpz_or_int:
    int
    mpz
```

But Cython complains about the fact that I do operations with this type (like `%`, even though it is defined for both of the types). The errors I got are:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
...
ctypedef fused mpz_or_int:
    int
    mpz

cdef class TestModularNumber:
    cdef readonly mpz_or_int value, modulo                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

finite_field/testmodular.pxd:12:36: Type is not specialized
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from gmpy2 import invert, powmod


cdef class TestModularNumber:
    def __cinit__(self, mpz_or_int value, mpz_or_int modulo):
        self.value = value
           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

finite_field/testmodular.pyx:7:12: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        if not self.has_modular_square_root():
            raise ValueError(f"{self.value} is a non-residue modulo {self.modulo}.")
        if self.value == 0 or self.value == 1:
            return TestModularNumber(self.value, self.modulo)

        if self.modulo % 4 == 3:
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

finite_field/testmodular.pyx:145:23: Compiler crash in AnalyseExpressionsTransform
```

For now, I copy/pasted the two classes, but that's a dirty hack, and obviously, every time that I have to modify a method of these classes, I cry :)

I think the way to go is using fused types, but how can I find a workaround to this problem?

Comment: This is a pretty similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436593/cython-templates-in-python-class-wrappers. Unfortunately I don't think any new solutions have emerged. Basically you probably do need to copy and paste, but you could try automating that

Comment: Damned, hoped there would be a prettier solution :'( Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: It would definitely be nice. I do actually have another thought that might work for your specific case...

Comment: Really? What would be the workaround, or at least is principle, so I can think about it too?

Comment: I've posted by suggestion as an answer. It's pretty vague and incomplete but I think it should help you avoid some code duplication. If it turns out not to work then tell me and I'll get rid of it (so not to mislead anyone else)

Comment: I'll try it by the end of the day for sure and will tell you then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For reasons explained in the [Cython: templates in python class wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436593/cython-templates-in-python-class-wrappers) this generally isn't available in Cython. `cdef classes` can't have fused members. In the answer to that question I proposed using the "copy/paste" method, but maybe trying to automate it.

For this specific case I wonder if you could do a bit better by taking the implementation out of the class into separate `cdef` fused functions. First define a fused class for your `cdef classes`

```
ctypedef fused cdef_pz_or_int:
    # cdef classes _can_ be part of fused types
    TestModularNumber
    TestInheritance
```

I'd recommend not having any inheritance relationship between the classes - just have them implement a (semi-)common interface.

The actual implementation is then in non-member fused functions:

```
cdef has_modular_square_root(cdef_pz_or_int self):
    value = self.value  # cython should be able to infer this type
    # more logic goes here....
```

You could obviously mix and match `cdef_pz_or_int` and `pz_or_int` as arguments (if you need to do so) however it'd probably need to generate valid code for all combinations.

---

I'm not 100% confident this will work for you - if not I'm happy to delete it.

Comment: Just to be sure (I'm quite new in Cython): if this method works, then I would have working functions, but these functions would not be accessible as methods, right? Plus, most of the class code (everything but the square root method actually) are magic functions to handle operators like `__add__`. Hence, can I really use this method? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I think you understand correctly. Depending on how big contents of the functions are it might still be worthwhile - you could define `def __add__(self, other): return add_function(self, other)`. If there's a lot of code in `add_function` then that's worth it. If not then it isn't. It sounds like it may not work for you though